# Holding onto an array marshalled into C# from C++

Tags: c#, interop, marshalling, com-interop

I am passing an array of integers from C++ to C#, using a parameter like this in my C# method:

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 0)] 
UInt32[] myStuff,
```

When this data arrives in the CLR, I think that "LPArray" indicates that I am working with the pointer from the C++-world directly? So if I want to hold onto this array after the method call is over, should I make a copy of it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful that this is allocated using the same memory allocation mechanisms in both the managed and unmanaged worlds. And even if that's the case, it's just safer to make a copy and work with that.

Note: In your example, the *pointer* isn't passed by reference, and so the callee can only add to your previous array, not give you a new array. Is that really what you intended?

Comment: Yes, this is what I intended. The caller is just passing some information to the callee. I don't understand what you're saying about memory allocation?

Comment: The problem is, if you're *receiving* an array *from* unmanaged code, that implies that either the code is writing into a preexisting array (in which case you were already the owner anyway), or it's giving you a new array (in which case it would need to modify the pointer to the array), and neither one seems to be exactly the case here.

Comment: My managed code is receiving a bunch of information in an integer array (which was allocated on the stack in native code and will disappear after the call).

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhh all right, that explains a lot. So you're providing a managed *callback* to the native code, right? Edit: I *think* that what happens is that the runtime creates a copy of the array for you automatically; if you need the original, get a pointer instead. (The array doesn't reference unmanaged memory, since arrays are objects and object references only point to managed memory.)

Comment: ok, thanks. it's not really a managed callback, I am accessing the managed code as a COM object. it's hard to find information about it online, most of the information is for going the other way ;)

Comment: Ah, okay. Yeah, documentation on COM interop isn't great... a lot of it comes down to guessing and checking sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Calling from unmanaged code into managed code (C++ to C#), the array gets copied into a fully managed array.  This array will be freed when the garbage collector notices that nobody has any more references to it, not when the function exits.

But the other direction is more dangerous:  If you were going the other direction (C# to C++), it would either: pin the C# array so it won't move, or make a temporary copy of the array into unmanaged memory (which gets freed when the function returns).  In either case, it would not be safe to hold onto the array on the C++ side after the function call completes, you'd want to copy the contents to somewhere else.